# Swift 5 Value of type has no member

Tags: ios, swift

I created a swift xcframework with a single public func:

```
public func getClientWithCompletion(clientId: String, completion: @escaping (Result<Client, Error>) -> Void) {
    let urlString = "https://api-here.com"
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, resp, err) in
        if let err = err {
            completion(.failure(err))
            return
        }
        
        do {
            let client = try JSONDecoder().decode(Client.self, from: data!)
            print("client: ", client)
            print("client name: ", client.name)
            completion(.success(client))
        } catch let jsonError {
            completion(.failure(jsonError))
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

The two print statements look correct. I'm seeing the client:

```
Client(name: "Blueprint")
```

and the client name:

```
Blueprint
```

Here is the Client struct

```
public struct Client {
    let name: String
}

extension Client: Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
    }
}
```

However, when I call this function from a demo project I'm not able to access the member `name`:

```
astra.getClientWithCompletion(clientId: "7ce19ab3d29c4680b1f9e7e135472bec") { res in
    switch res {
    case .success(let client):
        print(client) <-- prints fine
        print("new way of showing client: ", client.name) <-- Value of type 'Client' has no member 'name'
                
    case .failure(let error):
        print("failure: ", error)
    }
}
```

What is going on here where I can't access the name member of Client on the demo app?

Comment: Add `public` to `let name: String`.

Comment: To put it another way: in a framework, `public` is purely opt-in. Everything not explicitly declared `public` is invisible from outside the framework. Your Client is thus `public` but its `name` is not. So your "demo project" can see that there is a Client type but it cannot see that it has a `name` property.

Comment: Thank you both, that's exactly what it was. Not sure why the question is being downvoted?

Comment: Perhaps because some trivially easy consultation of the [docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html) would have sufficed? In general Stack Overflow doesn't like having its time wasted.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm just starting to learn Swift so it wasn't clear to me that this was the reason I couldn't access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you define a type’s access level as internal or public (or use the
> default access level of internal without specifying an access level
> explicitly), the default access level of the type’s members will be
> internal.

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html

I hate that, and wish it worked like you were thinking it would. The big problem with it is inconsistency: `public` will cascade down, but only in a `public extension`. As such, I recommend using extensions for access grouping. You can't do that with stored properties, though.